# Does HK 7-Days Transit visa-free policy still exist?

Tags: visas, transit, hong-kong

Many source references that HK has transit visa-free policy which allows any people enter to HK not more than 7 days when he/she holds a ticket to 3rd country and vaild visa, regardless his/her nationality.

However I cannot find any statement related to this in immigration office website nor other HK government website.

Does HK GOV still offer 7days transit visa-free policy?

Answer (score 5):

**No**, that does not appear to be the case anymore.  The authoritative reference appears to be the [Visit Visa / Entry Permit Requirements for the Hong Kong Special Administrative Region](http://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/visit-transit/visit-visa-entry-permit.html#notes), by the Immigration Department (last updated July 2015), and it makes it quite clear that there are three separate categories that countries fall into:

1. **Visa free** for visit not exceeding N days (where N is 14-90)
2. **Always require visa, except in direct transit by air** and when the person does not leave the airport transit area
3. All nationals are required to hold a valid visa for the HKSAR **for whatever purpose (including those who are in transit and remain on the airside)**.

...plus a few minor exceptions for diplomatic/official passport holders only, and the major exceptions of mainland China & Taiwan which have entirely separate procedures.